# Convert Platform::Array<byte> to String

Tags: c++, string, windows-runtime, c++-cx

A have a function in C++ from a library that reads a resource and returns `Platform::Array<byte>^`

How can I convert this into a `Platform::String` or an `std::string`

```
BasicReaderWriter^ m_basicReaderWriter = ref new BasicReaderWriter()
Platform::Array<byte>^ data = m_basicReaderWriter ("file.txt")
```

I need a `Platform::String` from `data`

Comment: For `std::string`, at least, I would imagine it's compatible with the iterator pair constructor.

Comment: What is the encoding of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `Platform::Array<byte>^ data` contains an ASCII string (as you clarified in a comment to your question), you can convert it to `std::string` using proper `std::string` constructor overloads (note that `Platform::Array` offers STL-like `begin()` and `end()` methods):

```
// Using std::string's range constructor
std::string s( data->begin(), data->end() );

// Using std::string's buffer pointer + length constructor
std::string s( data->begin(), data->Length );
```

Unlike `std::string`, `Platform::String` contains **Unicode UTF-16** (`wchar_t`) strings, so you need a conversion from your original byte array containing the ANSI string to Unicode string. You can perform this conversion using [ATL conversion helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class `CA2W` (which wraps calls to Win32 API `MultiByteToWideChar()`).
Then you can use `Platform::String` constructor taking a raw UTF-16 character pointer:

```
Platform::String^ str = ref new String( CA2W( data->begin() ) );
```

**Note:**
I currently don't have VS2012 available, so I haven't tested this code with the C++/CX compiler. If you get some argument matching errors, you may want to consider `reinterpret_cast<const char*>` to convert from the `byte *` pointer returned by `data->begin()` to a `char *` pointer (and similar for `data->end()`), e.g.

```
std::string s( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data->begin()), data->Length );
```

Comment: that's it. Not being able to use STL directly in WinRT is a complication.